# Why I received email from woo commerce in html format via hotmail account using outlook

Tags: html, wordpress, email, outlook, woocommerce

I am receiving an email from a woo commerce order in good format on gmail, per the attached image:

[image]

Then I added a new hotmail email in woo commerce. That email account is configured on Outlook. But when the email is received in outlook the email format is HTML that does not resemble that image. Why?

Comment: I'd be more concerned over those blue boxes randomly appearing on your email... Anyway - different clients render differently, check out https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/